# Nativescript Error: Build failed. Only 8, 16, 24, or 32 bits supported: 872

Tags: android, webpack, nativescript

when i try to make cloud builds of my nativescript andriod app everything seems to go well then the following error shows up:

Build failed. Only 8, 16, 24, or 32 bits supported: 872

I have even converted my .jks keystore to .p12 but the error persists

I have tried all the suggestions from the following links:

https://github.com/NativeScript/sidekick-feedback/issues/244

https://github.com/NativeScript/sidekick-feedback/issues/186

https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/6157

but still no solution

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem. I am currently updating java so I can get pkcs12 generated directly: https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android

Comment: I managed to solve it using latest java version and by setting `JAVA_HOME`: https://github.com/shirakaba/react-nativescript/issues/45